# ERROR in ./node_modules/jpeg-exif/lib/index.js In @react-pdf/renderer its giving this error

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

After upgrading React to the latest version, I encountered this error in my React app.

> ERROR in ./node_modules/jpeg-exif/lib/index.js 3:10-23 Module not
> found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'D:\lecture1\node_modules\jpeg-exif\lib'

I executed NPM after removing the node_modules and package-lock.json files, but it didn't work.

Comment: Look into the package that's causing this it might be react/pdf-renderer. if so check  it out they have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I took this answer form github but it works try it out.

Bellow solution worked for me.

npm i @craco/craco or yarn add @craco/craco

Create craco.config.js in the root of your project.

Bellow code in craco.config.js

```
webpack: {
configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
webpackConfig.resolve.fallback = {
fs: false,
os: false,
path: false,
};
return webpackConfig;
},
},
};
```

modify your package.json
"build": "craco build",
"start": "craco start",
"test": "craco test",

yarn install or npm update